# Installing Git Unit

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, git

I am trying to install git using my yum command

Following is the error log

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.8.2.1-1.el5 for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Error) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.6()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libexpat.so.0()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.6()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libexpat.so.0()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
---> Package perl-Error.noarch 1:0.17010-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) for package: 1:perl-Error-0.17010-1.el5.noarch
---> Package perl-Git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) for package: perl-Git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
---> Package perl-TermReadKey.x86_64 0:2.30-4.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) for package: perl-TermReadKey-2.30-4.el5.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libssl.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libexpat.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: perl-Git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: perl-TermReadKey-2.30-4.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: 1:perl-Error-0.17010-1.el5.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

The command `yum repolist`

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
repo id                                                                     repo name                                                                                                          status
epel                                                                        Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64                                                                      7,351
rpmforge                                                                    RHEL 6Server - RPMforge.net - dag                                                                                  11,275
repolist: 18,626
```

Please help me install and resolve these missing dependencies

```
uname --kernel-release
2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: Please share the actual yum command you're using in the above scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Try disabling the RPMForge repo

Do the command as follows:

```
$ sudo yum --disablerepo=rpmforge install git
```

The repositories EPEL and RPMForge don't get along that well.

#### Mixing EPEL6 repos with EPEL5?

If the above doesn't resolve the issue then it would appear that you're mixing EPEL6 repositories with your CentOS 5 installation. In looking at a CentOS 5 installation I have here I have the following repositories:

```
$ yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
repo id                                  repo name                                                                            status
base                                     CentOS-5 - Base                                                                       3,641
convirt                                  ConVirt repository                                                                        4
convirt-dep                              ConVirt Dependencies                                                                      7
elrepo                                   ELRepo.org Community Enterprise Linux Repository - el5                                  412
extras                                   CentOS-5 - Extras                                                                       270
rpmforge                                 RHEL 5 - RPMforge.net - dag                                                          11,275
updates                                  CentOS-5 - Updates                                                                      447
repolist: 16,056
```

See what versions of `git` I have outside of RPMForge:

```
$ sudo yum --disablerepo=rpmforge list all git*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.nexcess.net
 * elrepo: elrepo.org
 * extras: centos.mirrors.tds.net
 * updates: mirrors.einstein.yu.edu
Installed Packages
git.x86_64                                                1.7.10.4-1.el5.rf                                                installed
```

The above shows that if I disable RPMForge, the only version of `git` available for my mix of repos is the one coming from RPMForge, and the latest version is 1.7.

Given this It would appear that you're mixing a package from CentOS 6, would be my guess.

#### References

- [Is it stable to use epel and rpmforge in the same time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50657/is-it-stable-to-use-epel-and-rpmforge-in-the-same-time)
- [Installing RPMforge](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge)

Comment: After running the above command I still get the same error

Comment: @AnandSunderraman - Sorry I gave you the wrong command, please try the updated answer now. Sorry about that.

Comment: thanks but the updated command also returns the same error.

Comment: Where are the rest of your repo's in that `yum repolist` command? I get these:  base, epel, extras, updates, rpmforge on CentOS 5.

Comment: @AnandSunderraman - Can you look in your `/etc/yum.repo.d/*` files and make sure you're not pointing to EL6 repos? I don't see 1.8 available in the epel for EL5. I think you're mixing repos.

Answer (score 0):

The problem on the CentOS 6 server I was working on was that EPEL 5 was installed 
I found this through the following command.

```
sudo yum repolist
```

I solved this through the following commands:

```
wget http://mirror.umd.edu/fedora/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
sudo yum remove epel-release
sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm --test
sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
sudo yum update
```